# type 'List<List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I am getting this error when debug my code

**type 'List<List>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)**

I'm not willing to add **json.encode(data)** in body, that is because the **server don't take the request as raw** so i have to specify the body as **form-data.**
[image]

any help please

```
class CartConfirmatinoAPi {
  static const API = kDevelopmentMobile;
  static const key = {
    'KEY': "***************************",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  };

  Future orderConfirmation(CartConfirmationModel cd, orderNotifyData) {
    var dataMap = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    final List orders = [];

    for (var item in orderNotifyData.items) {
      var productMap = {
        'product_id': item.productId,
        'qty': item.qty,
      };
      orders.add(productMap);
    }

    dataMap['customer_id'] = cd.customerId;
    
    dataMap['orderLine'] = orders; **// this is the line is causing the problem**

    return http // 
        .post(API + '/orders/create', headers: key, body: dataMap)
        .then((data) {
      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

        return jsonData['Result'];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

API Requiremtns

```
$result = [];
        
        $result['customer_id'] = $this->input->post('customer_id', true);

        $result['orderLine'] = $this->input->post('orderLine');

        $message = [
            'Code'    => 200,
            'Result'  => $result ? $result : []
        ];
        $this->response($message,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: First of all try to print **orders** and match the format with api requirements

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari - this the out put when i print the orders

Comment: [{product_id: 1, qty: 1}, {product_id: 2, qty: 1}, {product_id: 26, qty: 2}]

Comment: and what is the api requirement format?

Comment: updated my code, added API requiremtns

Comment: if comment dataMap['orderLine'] = orders; the code works fine

Comment: yes this is clear that data format is wrong , let me check

Answer (score 0):

According to the http package documentation

> [body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List] or
> a [Map<String, String>]

In your code dataMap is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`. At Runtime the value of your map is at some point of type `Map<String, List<dynamic>>`. So it tries to cast `List<dynamic>` to `String` which is obviously not possible.

This explains why your code works out when you comment `dataMap['orderLine'] = orders`.
Since `cd.customerId` is probably a String, At runtime the type of dataMap is Map<String,String>